# Setting the COM displayed name/ProgID of an Assembly/Class for COM Clients

Tags: .net, com

I'm setting up a .NET assembly that is being exposed to VB6 and the filename of the Assembly seems to be interfering with the name that VB6 uses when it creates the class.

I'm trying to find if there is a .NET attribute or setting that I can provide that will allow me to control the object instance that is created within VB6. It's purely an asthetic thing and I know that it will all just compile down, but I like things to look nice.

On my .NET assembly I have the following Attributes, note well that the ProgID seems to make no difference whatsoever to the compilation.

```
<
ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(IManagerEvents)),
Guid(Manager.ClassId),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ProgId("IdealposWebIt.Manager")
> _
Public Class Manager
    Implements IManager
```

Over in the VB6 world when referencing this class, it seems to be the Filename of the assembly gets mangled to become the part of the ProgID.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim orderManager As Idealpos_WebIT_Connector.Manager
    Set orderManager = New Idealpos_WebIT_Connector.Manager
```

Is there anything I can do to change it? Should I just suck it up princess.

Do note that everything is creating and running correctly inside VB6, but I'd just like it to display nicely.

Comment: The ProgID *is* the ProgID. That exposed name is something else. e.g. `CreateObject("IdealposWebIt.Manager")` should work as expected if it's registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, and reviewing C++ materials that without having a MIDL compiler in .NET you can't control the name that is exposed to COM.

Whatever name you use in the Assembly Name of your Project is that name that gets COMified for use in COM based applications (Early Bind). So in this case, in the project the Assembly Name is `Idealpos.WebIT.Connector` which then becomes `Idealpos_WebIT_Connector` so to make a shorter name for COM you would have to change your .NET project name which is not always something you are willing to do.

I hope this helps people in the future.